# Show Activity on notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Recently I have seen that Whatsapp added a new service - whatsapp call.

I was wondering how was it implemented. How could the application display an Activity (Which is the incoming call dialog http://thefusejoplin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/WhatsApp-2.12.16-Free-Voice-Calls.jpg) on the main screen even when the phone is locked, just like a regular phone call.

I would like to implement it too, is there a good reference that can help me do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now they are probably using push messages to get the event of a "phone" call. That message is probably intercepted by a wakeful broadcast receiver, which than starts a wakeful intent service. The service will process the message and fully wake your phone if the message is valid (guy calling is in your phone book or something) and dismiss the keyguard (lockscreen) and start the activity with the answer call and other options...
If it does not get a valid message it will most probably ignore it and shut itself down.

Comment: Do you know any good open-source reference for implementing it? I'm having hard time googling it.

Comment: Really? Google has wrote a really good article about google cloud messaging  https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: If you are making a cross platform solution, you can look at parse push messages, urbanairship or making your own backend

Comment: It is not the push notifications that concerns me, It is the invoke of the Activity when it is received.